# Laravel: @foreach does not render content within

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I'm creating a simple @foreach but for some reason it is ignored completely. I made sure that the data exists. I var_dumped both in the controller and in the view and the variables do exist.

Controller Code:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $dawrat = Dawra::all();
        $ainshams = University::where('name', '=', 'عين شمس')->first();

        $faculties = Faculty::where('university_id', '=', $ainshams->id);

        return view('createDawra', ['faculties' => $faculties]);
    }
```

My view:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
@foreach ( $faculties as $faculty)
    <label class="btn btn-danger " id="collg1">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">{{ $faculty->name }}
    </label>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: What's the filename of the view? Did you put the `.blade`?

Comment: why not to use relation on eloquent?

Comment: @ChinLeung I literally read your comment and immediately understood where I was going wrong. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `->get()`:

```
$faculties = Faculty::where('university_id', '=', $ainshams->id)->get()
```

From Laravel [Eloquent Retrieving Models Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models):

> Since each Eloquent model serves as a query builder, you may also add constraints to queries, and then use the get method to retrieve the results